# How to pass argument in callback function in php?

Tags: php

I have Repository class with a method as follows:

```
public function GetOne($id){
    $method = __METHOD__;
    $post = null;


    $post = $this->CacheManager($method, function($id) {
        return DB::select("select * from posts where id = ?", [$id]);
    });

    return $post;
}
```

I want to cache the result, but in the closure/callback function the $id parameter is not working. The CacheManager is a trait where I'm using it in my repository.

```php
public function CacheManager($method, $fn) {
  $obj = null;

  if(!$this->HasCache($method)){
    $obj = $fn();
  }else {
    $obj = $this->GetCache($method);
  }

  return $obj;
}
```

I have some other methods without parameters and they're working as intended.

Comment: Well, you never passed the `$id` to `CacheManager` nor did you pass it to `$fn();`. You need to pass the arguments as well.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). :D

With the `use` clause, you can import variables from the parent scope into the scope of the function.

```
public function GetOne($id){
    $method = __METHOD__;
    $post = null;


    $post = $this->CacheManager($method, function() use ($id) {
        return DB::select("select * from posts where id = ?", [$id]);
    });

    return $post;
}
```

Just a side note. Since it looks you are building a caching mechanism, you will need to include the ID in the cache as well. Currently you only check by `$method`, but for each id you will probably have a different cache entry which may or may not exist. So I think in your function you need to do something like the line below to make the cache key more unique. I would also call the parameter `$method` something like `$cacheKey` instead, since to the cache it shouldn't be linked to a method name per se.

```
$method = __METHOD__ . ";$id";
```

**Update for PHP 7.4: arrow functions**

The [RFC for arrow functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2) (AKA 'short closures') has passed voting.

With these you don't specify the parameters you want to close in, because they can only have a single expression anyway, so any expression/value they use can (and will) be taken from the parent function scope.

Since in this case the anonymous function just has a single statement, it can be rewritten into an arrow function. The call to the cache manager will then look like this:

```
public function GetOne($id){
    $method = __METHOD__;
    $post = null;

    $post = $this->CacheManager($method, fn() => DB::select("select * from posts where id = ?", [$id]));

    return $post;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$fn()` needs an argument ...

```
if(!$this->HasCache($method)){
    $obj = $fn($id);
}
```