# Trying to pass callback function with parameters as a function argument - getting "Unexpected callbackFunctionName, expecting '(' " error

Tags: php, callback, anonymous-function, declare, callable-object

I am trying to use [this open source PHP class](https://github.com/rstuven/php-timers/blob/master/Timers.class.php) and call the **setInterval()** function. From the linked github page:

```
/**
 * Just for simplifying the Timers::setInterval method
 *
 *
 * @param callable | string $func
 * @param float $milliseconds
 *
 * @return integer
 */
function setInterval ($func, $milliseconds)
{
    return Timers::setInterval($func, $milliseconds);
}
```

As you can see, it takes a function as the first argument, so I tried to pass it a ***callback function***, and [followed this SO answer for the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035355/how-to-pass-argument-in-callback-function-in-php#answer-35035423). Here is my code:

```
declare(ticks=1) {
            setInterval(function callbackFunction() use $someArrayFromOuterScope {

                    runSomeOtherFunction();
                    //Do something

            }, $someArrayFromOuterScope[0]["time"]);
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected callbackFunction, expecting '('

So the question is that what am I doing wrong here, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Anyonymous functions should not have a name. That's your syntax error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
    function setInterval ($func, $milliseconds)
    {
        return Timers::setInterval($func, $milliseconds);
    }
    declare(ticks=1) {
        setInterval(function($someArrayFromOuterScope) {

                runSomeOtherFunction();
                //Do something

        }, $someArrayFromOuterScope[0]["time"]);
    }
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)