# Laravel: Using external variable after processing data?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function `getUnfilledOrders` where I get Orders from the database and then use `chunk` to have them go to `checkStatus` 10 at a time.  If I have 100 orders, the flow I believe would happen is `checkStatus` get will get called 10 times (since there are 100 orders).
Now once that completes, I want to have access to $totalOrders in `getUnfulfilledOrders`.  Is this possible?

```
protected function getUnfulfilledOrders()
{
    Order::where('order_status', '!=', true)
        ->where('tracking_number', '!=', null)
        ->limit(3000)
        ->chunk(10, function ($unfulfilledOrders) {
            $this->checkStatus($unfulfilledOrders);
        });

   // how to do something now with $totalOrders once ALL Orders are processed 10 at a time;

}

protected function checkStatus($unfilledOrders)
{
    $totalOrders = array();

    foreach ($unfulfilledOrders as $unfulfilledOrder) {
         // logic here
         array_push($totalOrders, $unfulFilledOrder->id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```php
protected function getUnfulfilledOrders()
{
    $totalOrders = [];

    Order::where('order_status', '!=', true)
        ->where('tracking_number', '!=', null)
        ->limit(3000)
        // Add use (&$totalOrders)
        ->chunk(10, function ($unfulfilledOrders) use (&$totalOrders) {
            $totalOrders = array_merge($totalOrders, $this->checkStatus($unfulfilledOrders));
        });

   // how to do something now with $totalOrders once ALL Orders are processed 10 at a time;

}

protected function checkStatus($unfilledOrders)
{
    $totalOrders = array();

    foreach ($unfulfilledOrders as $unfulfilledOrder) {
         // logic here
         array_push($totalOrders, $unfilledOrder->id);
    }

    // Return the generated array
    return $totalOrders;
}
```

Here I initiated an empty array at the start of `getUnfulfilledOrders()` and merged anything returned by `checkStatus()` into it.

[More on `use ($var)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035355/how-to-pass-argument-in-callback-function-in-php)

[More on passing by reference (`&$var`)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: ah smart approach, thanks! What does `// Add use (&$totalOrders)` mean?  I will definitely use this approach but just curious if another way to do it would be by creating a global variable?  I come from a JS background but I assume PHP has this?

Comment: The callbacks in PHP don't have access to outside variables by itself. You need to add `use ($var)` in order to be able to access a var from outside scope. But by default `use ($var)` passes in a "copy" of the variable, so doing anything with it wouldn't have an effect on the variable outside of the callback. Prefixing it with `&` however, passes the variable by reference so that any changes made within the callback will change the variable outside of the callback as well.

Comment: great explanation , Thanks!!